# How to remove initialisations on page change in Next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to use OneSignal for notifications and they initialise it like this....

```
OneSignal.push(function () {
  OneSignal.init({
    appId: self.props.data.pushAppId,
    notifyButton: {
      enable: true,
    },
    allowLocalhostAsSecureOrigin: true,
  })
})
```

Which works great cause I only want it shown in certain pages so it lives in componentDidMount.
When I navigate away from that page it doesn't remove the bell notification so it continues to exist on pages that I do not initialise it on.

How can I (in componentWillUnmount i'm guessing) remove the instance of it gets destroyed on page change.

It will remove on hard refresh of other pages but router changes it doesn't get removed.

Thanks

[image]